# i want to define a cutoff range like a<cutoff<b in r

Tags: r

I am a novice at R. I want to define a cutoff range but couldn't code it. The cut-off point is matching the data in a vector to see whether it is in between `a` and `b`. For example `a<cutoff<b`.

I tried the following code:

```
Heat_MAP_Z_900 = matrix(data=0,nrow=ncol(Z),ncol=ncol(D))
cut_off>300 && cut_off<900
for(i in 1:ncol(Z)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(D)) {
    Heat_MAP_Z_900[i,j] = sum(Z[i,]*(D[j,]<cut_off))
  }
}
```

The code `cut_off>300 && cut_off<900` but it is not working. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You need to add a sample of your data and your actual code. Also, type 
`?"&"` into your console and read about the difference between using `&` and `&&`.

Comment: `subset(your_data,cut_off>300 & cut_off<900)` should work.

Comment: Heat_MAP_Z_900 = matrix(data=0,nrow=ncol(Z),ncol=ncol(D))
cut_off>300 && cut_off<900

for(i in 1:ncol(Z))
{
  for(j in 1:ncol(D))
  {
    Heat_MAP_Z_900[i,j] = sum(Z[i,]*(D[j,]<cut_off))
  }
}
thanks for your reply, i have pasted the R -code for your convenience. in the mean time i am working on ur advice

Answer (score 0):

From the sample code you provided, it seems like you're trying to multiply matrix Z by a matrix of binary values that indicate if each element in D is within the range (300, 900). In general you should use the `%*%` operator to multiply matrices instead of individually taking the dot product of each row and column. In your case, you would want:

```
Heat_MAP_Z_900 <- Z %*% (D > 300 & D < 900)
```